# This code creating the folder in INTERNAL STORAGE Everytime ,I need to create folder in my SDCARD

Tags: android

Why does this code only create a new folder in the internal storage and not create the folder on the SD Card.

Thanks

**Code:**

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Akshay");

        if(!direct.exists()) {
               if(direct.mkdir()); //directory is created;
        }
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 'Akshay');
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: Firstly , Character literal having more than one character so it is already not worked by watching the code

Comment: although,If I change this to string and then running the code no error nothing BUT it is also creating folder in INTERNAL STORAGE

Comment: Add both permissions `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`